# Will lambda retry logic work with standard sqs invocation?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

My project flow is:

**CloudWatch >> SQS >> Lambda**

Cloudwatch invokes the standard SQS and SQS invokes the lambda function.

As per documentation , lambda retry logic works in async invocation however the SQS is based on polling machanism and that follows the sync behaviour. That is my understanding.

Problem:-

I tested my code with two scenario :-

1. lambda retry 0 : That time everything worked fine for me and my lambda run 3 times.
2. Lambda retry 2 :- That time lambda retries and messageId was 2 different ids and lambda function runs 6 times.

Output of 2nd senario:-

```
2020-09-24T20:02:52.222+05:30
MessageId : 5a8f5dbd-b07d-4c80-9d34-e5efb1002b3b
ApproximateReceiveCount:1

2020-09-24T20:03:51.047+05:30
MessageId :15ae23e3-472c-4d6e-99a6-8a248dae353e
"ApproximateReceiveCount": "1"

2020-09-24T20:07:50.863+05:30
MessageId :5a8f5dbd-b07d-4c80-9d34-e5efb1002b3b
"ApproximateReceiveCount": "2"

2020-09-24T20:08:50.963+05:30
MessageId :15ae23e3-472c-4d6e-99a6-8a248dae353e
"ApproximateReceiveCount": "2"

2020-09-24T20:12:50.652+05:30
MessageId :5a8f5dbd-b07d-4c80-9d34-e5efb1002b3b
"ApproximateReceiveCount": "3"

2020-09-24T20:13:50.347+05:30
MessageId :15ae23e3-472c-4d6e-99a6-8a248dae353e
"ApproximateReceiveCount": "3"
```

Sqs Visibility timeout is : 5 min.

So , my questions are 
**What could be the reason of above data behaviour ?

As per my project flow, lambda retry logic should work or not ?**

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what do you mean? Which `lambda retry 0`? Which option exact;y is it? What messages, did you submit them manually? How many of them? What's wrong with the behavior observed?

Comment: In lambda retry option we have 0, 1 , 2 options . This feature allows user to set the number of times lambda should be retry in case of failure .

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me there is some misunderstanding of "lambda retry option we have 0, 1 , 2 options" and its relation to [event source mapping with sqs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html).

The **retry option does not apply** in this case. You can set it to whatever you want, it will have no effect on retrying delivering your sqs messages to lambda. This is because retries in this case are only controlled by SQS settings. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-retries.html):

> **Event source mappings** For event source mappings that read from a queue, **you determine** the length of time between retries and destination for failed events by configuring the visibility timeout and **redrive policy on the source queue**.

In other words, the retries in your case are only controlled from the SQS queue settings, not from lambda.

Comment: Yes .. i have same understand . So means lambda retry machanism will not work while use SQS right ?

Comment: @PratapChauhan Yes. The option has no effect. Its all managed on the SQS side.

Comment: Thank you .. i feel the same however sometime i see the weird behaviour. If you check the above posted logs ... those suppose to be 3 logs because the maxcount is 3 but i received 6 logs and first two logs have only 1 min difference and ApproximateReceiveCount is 1 and messageID is different same are following the next one . So i feel lambda retries also worked here or it might happen because of my code issue.

Comment: @PratapChauhan There must be something else happening which is not apparent from your question. I would recommend creating most basic lambda with sqs, and experimenting with it and how the retries work if the functions throws an exception.